# Autofilter with out selecting sheet

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I want to use autofilter to delete some rows without selecting the sheet

If the sheet `is` selected the code runs

If the sheet is `not` selected the code fails I get the error `object required` and `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped")` is highlighted`

the code fails even if I use `Select` when seting `ws`

I can not figure out why this is throwing the error possibly because I am using a array for the criteria?

Thanks

Edit: 10-29-14

```
Sub DeleteSomeNamesIn_LI_Data_Prepped()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim cNumber As Integer

'Does NOT work like this
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped").Select

'Does NOT work like this either
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped")

With ws
     lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter
    .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Alis", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'If no rows to delete will error
     On Error Resume Next
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need `.Select` to set ws. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped")` should do it.

Comment: Hello Jeeped, that's what I thought but the code does not work with or without `Select` it `only` runs if the sheet is `pr-selected` before the code is executed

Comment: If you are running code (e.g. DeleteSomeNamesIn_LI_Data_Prepped) that is not contained in the workbook that houses the LI_Data_Prepped worksheet, then use `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped")` and run the code when that workbook is in the foreground. `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook that contains the sub procedure. [Application.ThisWorkbook Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193227(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid pre-selecting the worksheet:

Use `Set ws = Worksheets("LI_Data_Prepped")` instead of

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LI_Data_Prepped").Select
```

You can also use `Dim ws As Worksheet` instead of `Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet`